A Cubic Complex Inequality
A homework question:
If it true that, if $Re(z)\ge1$ then $|1+z+z^2+z^3|>|z|^3-1$?
I used Maple to plot this inequality, with $z$ ranging from $1-100i$ to $100+100i$, and it seems to hold. So, my guess is that it holds in the entire range, but I have no idea how to prove it.
A last point to mention is that this question comes in the beginning of a Complex Analysis course, after the very basic properties of complex numbers are introduced, so the solution should be elementary...
Thanks for your help!

Avoiding too much brute force, start with the well-known inequality $|1+w|\ge ||w|-1|$ to obtain: $|1+z+z^2+z^3|\ge ||z+z^2+z^3|-1| \tag{1}$ First establish that $|z+z^2+z^3|-1 = |z||1+z+z^2|-1> 0$. Since $\Re (z) > 1$, we have that $|z|>1$, so it is enough to show $|1+z+z^2|> 1$. This can be done by writing explicitely $z = x + i y$ and, to avoid roots,  verifying $(1+z+z^2)(1+z+z^2)^* -1 > 0$ or $(1 + x + iy+ (x + iy)^2)(1 + x - iy+ (x - iy)^2)-1> 0$. Expanding the brackets (the only brute force used here ...) gives $(x^2 + y^2)^2 + 2 x^3 + 3 x^2 +  2 x  + (2 x -1)y^2 \tag{2}$ which, since $x = \Re (z) \ge1$, is  $> 0$.
Having established that, we can write eq. (1) as $|1+z+z^2+z^3|\ge |z+z^2+z^3|-1 $.
So in the original task it suffices to prove  $|z+z^2 + z^3| > |z^3|$ or
$|1+z+z^2| > |z^2|$. This can be done by verifying $(1+z+z^2)(1+z+z^2)^*  - |z^2|^2=   [(1+z+z^2)(1+z+z^2)^* -1] - (x^2 + y^2)^2 + 1  > 0$. Using eq. (2) for the part $[\cdots ]$ gives $2 x^3 + 3 x^2 +  2 x  + 1 + (2 x -1)y^2 > 0$ which, since $x \ge1$, is again certainly $> 0$, so we are done. $ \qquad \square $

By triangular inequality we have that
$$|1+z+z^2+z^3|\ge |z+z^2+z^3|-1 \stackrel ?\ge |z|^3-1$$
and the latter is true, indeed
$$|z+z^2+z^3|-1\ge |z|^3-1 \iff |1+z+z^2|>|z^2|\tag 1$$

To prove $(1)$ let $z=r w$ with $r=|z|$, $w=e^{i\theta}$, then
$$|1+z+z^2|>|z|^2 \iff |1+z+z^2|^2>r^4 $$
with
$$|1+z+z^2|^2=(1+rw+r^2w^2)(1+r\bar w+r^2\bar w^2)=$$
$$=1+(r+r^3)(w+\bar w)+r^2(w^2+\bar w^2+1)+r^4=\ldots$$
and since

$w+\bar w =2\cos \theta$
$w^2+\bar w^2 =2\cos (2\theta)=4\cos^2 \theta-2$

we have
$$\ldots =1+2(r+r^3)\cos \theta+r^2(4\cos^2 \theta-1)+r^4=\ldots$$
and by $u=r\cos \theta=\Re(z)\ge 1$ we obtain
$$\ldots =1+2u+2ur^2+4u^2-r^2+r^4$$
such that $(1)$ reduces to
$$(2u-1)r^2+4u^2+2u+1>0$$
which is true.
